# Overflow issue with Math functions

Tags: excel, vba

I created a new WORKBOOK and created a new MODULE "Module_Trigonometry" and there I implemented the FUNCTION "KursWinkel" I use to name variables, macros and functions in German
to evade conflicts with the compiler own variables, but here I have a very strange situation, in my workbook in "Developer-Tools" in "VBA" in the mainmenu the option "Compile" is greyen. and if I enter
in one of my sheets, e.g. "Channel" in one Cell "= Kurs" Excel propose my complete function with the round brace open and when I complete this with the reference to a cell containing a Sinus-value
and close the brace I  get an error in this cell "#Wert" (Value)
My Function is

```
Function KursWinkel(Sinus As Double) As Double
    'To get the angle for the value of the overgiven sinus-value we can only guess and this we do by
    'going throug the entire range of Double
    Dim s, r As Long
    For s = -4940656458412# To 494065645841247#
         If (Abs(Sinus) - Abs(s)) > r Then
           Exit For
        End If
        r = Abs(Sinus) - Abs(s)
    Next
    KursWinkel = r
End Function
```

What's wrong with this function

Comment: It's not a compile error, it's an overflow error when the code runs, try declaring r and s as Double instead of Long.

Comment: You seem to be trying to implement a linear search for an inverse value. If so, that is incredibly inefficient. Why not use something like Newton's method instead?

Comment: Not causing your problem, but `Dim s, r As Long` declares `s` as Variant, and `r` as long.  If that is what you want, fine.  But be aware that each variable needs to be declared individually.

Comment: You are right I already tried it with double then still "Compile" is greyed

Comment: It might help if you explained what the function is trying to compute

Comment: Hi there,
that's it, my function overflew the minimum number in an Excel-Cell https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3.
And I became aware that the whole thing doesn't work as desiren, a most important line is missing, my function has no reference to angle. The maximum sume of angle one can expect is 90°, 
that is sinus 0,412118485, so I reduce the range to search from -0,412118485 to 0,412118485
and I introduced another Double Variable to call the Sin-Function and with this result

Comment: Compile being greyed out doesn't mean the code can't be compiled, it means it doesn't need to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

My new funktion to get the angle from a sinus

```
Function SinusWinkel(Sinus As Double) As Double
  'To get the angle for the value of the overgiven sinus-value we can only guess and this we do by
  'going throug the sume of angle in a triangle, that is 90° or in sin 0,412118485
  'the range is consequently -0,412118485 to 0,412118485
  'A negative sin can result wether of a location east of Greenwich or a cours east to west.
  'This sub is determined to transformed to a function tha returns the angle to the cell.
  'therefore it's implemented in an own module to get rid of it when necessary.
  Dim i, k, l, d As Double
  For i = -0.412118485 To 0.412118485
    l = Sin(i)
    d = Abs(Sinus) - Abs(l)
    If (d) > k Then
      Exit For
    End If
    k = d
  Next
  SinusWinkel = k
End Function
```

I use this function in a Worksheet that contain a location and it's Latitude and Longituted,
the difference of Latitude is my Sinus, but to navigate I need the angle.